# Rake Deduction Logic

Tags: poker-theory, poker-strategy

I am writing an Online Poker Game and I was wondering about how the Rake will be deducted for each hand in a cash game.

I know there is rake percentage and rakecap concept and the rake is calculated based on pot size and if that amount is greater than rakecap we take rakecap amount, in short, we take the minimum of calculated rake and rakecap.

My question is with how to choose the rake percentage and rake cap values because there are two types of rake percentages I see 1 is rake percentage and then there is rake percentage(< 3) Which is actually the rake that needs to be considered when the number of players is less than 3.

Consider a scenario in which there are 4 players in the starting of hand:
In preflop 1 player goes all-in and others call leading to the main pot
In flop another player goes all-in and 1 player folds and 1 player call leading to side pot 1
No action is performed in turn and river

Now at showdown, we have **side pot 1** in which **2 players** are available and the **main pot** in which we have **4 players**

My question is should I select Normal Rake Percentage and Rake Cap for Main Pot (which has 4 players) and Rake Percentage Head's Up for Side Pot 1 (which has 2 players) **OR** Should I select only 1 rake percentage i.e normal rake percentage for both the pots since there are 4 players at the time of the start of the hand.

**Rake percentage is based on the number of players at the starting of the hand or number of players in the pot?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Rake percentage is based on the number of players at the starting of the hand or number of players in the pot?

The rake percentage typically remains static at some set percentage of the pot. Rake reduction is typically a discount on the rack cap. This is based on the number of players dealt in, which is no different the number of players in the pot. Once you have been dealt in you are in the pot.

You talked about side pots. The rack comes from the main pot first, if the main pot is not large enough to get all the rack you start racking the side pot(s) in order until you reach the rake cap.

Comment: If I understand it correctly rake percentage is set for each hand at the time of starting of hand based on the number of players playing that hand. Also, I need to understand that side pots are evaluated first and the main pot is evaluated at last and according to you I have to start deducting rake from main pot and then move to side pots till rake cap is met so I have to create a separate function for evaluating rake for that hand because currently I am evaluating side pot first and at last the main pot Thanks

Comment: Figure your rack as the bets get called. Sort of like metering the water coming into the house rather then at each appliance that uses the water. The main pot is always going to get filled first. You don't need to worry about what pot the chips are going into if you calculate the rack as the bets are made and called.